# Save >10000 records with CakePHP's saveMany()

Tags: php, cakephp, innodb, save, cakephp-2.1

I am trying to save a list of over 10000 records with CakePHP 2.1's method, `saveMany()`. But it gives me either a 500 error, or a 'memory exhausted' fatal error.

If I debug the whole array after it has been processed (so, without calling the save method), the time is under 0.05s. But when I add the save method (`$this->saveMany($save, array('validate' => false));`), it shows me one of the above errors.

I mention that I am using InnoDB as my storage engine in MySQL and PHP as the scripting language.

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix this?

**EDIT**

I am coming back to this issue because I "solved" why that huge number of records doesn't save. The reason is...well, not even one record is saved. I tested saving only the first element in the generated array and this is what it happens: it increases memory until the limit, then it dies. I've put it on my localhost with 2GB of memory, and it still gives me the memory exceeded error. It is very weird and I can't understand why is this happening. The same code applied on another model works as expected. I recreated the model and its table but with no success. The only reason I can think of is the length of the table name, but it makes no sense to me. What could generate this increase in memory just for a single record to be saved?

Comment: How often you need to do this? Where 10000 records comes from? You need to provide more information so people can suggest alternative approaches.

Comment: I am building a cache for my application, so that whenever I need to retrieve and compute some data, I'll only have to fetch several records from these 10000. I'll do this only a couple of times, manually. So the only requirement for the script is to actually work.

Comment: Updated my answer. Do you have access to MySQL console?

Comment: Thats strange. You should comment out all the validation rules in model to make sure they don't affect in any way. Try also with smaller resultset like 10 rows. Set debug to 2 and look at sql dump if there is something strange.

Comment: I solved the issue. I was overwriting a Cake method and causing an infinite loop. Quite silly. Thank you for all your help, will mark your answer as the one accepted :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could take a while to save 10000 rows. Make sure you have set php's time limit `set_time_limit(120);` big enough.

You could also try to save the records one by one like this:

```
foreach($save as $s){

    $this->create();
    $this->save($s, array('validate' => false));

}
```

EDIT 1:

But if the original data is coming from database you could copy it directly to cache table with MySQL console or using `$this->query();`

Or you could `SELECT` it `INTO OUTFILE` and the `LOAD DATA INFILE` it to the cache table.

EDIT 2:

Then only thing that comes to my mind is save data to text file on disk and read it in another function and save it as many rows at time that time/memory limit allows to. You could also try to save it on csv-file and use `$this->query('LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE xxx ...');`

Just comes to my mind that you should disable indexes before saving to make them faster. You can do it by using `$this->query('ALTER TABLE table DISABLE KEYS;');`

Comment: It still doesn't make it to the end. It issues again a memory exceeded error. I cannot change the memory/time limit because I am on a payed host.

Comment: I don't have access to the console and I really can't quite copy it because I need to perform some actions on the data from my tables. Only after the data has been modified for caching it should be saved.